# Vue - vuetify - Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'vuetify' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Created a new Vue project with TypeScript using the following guide:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

1. Install Vue CLI, if it's not already installed

   npm install --global @vue/cli
2. Create a new project, then choose the "Manually select features" option

   vue create my-project-name

Tested the project with `npm run serve` and it worked without a problem.

I then added `vuetify` by running `vue add vuetify`

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/

This caused some errors however:

> ERROR in
> C:/Test/vue-test/src/main.ts(13,3): 13:3
> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(options?:
> ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<Vue, object, object, object,
> never> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<Vue, object, object, object,
> Record<...>>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ router: VueRouter; store: Store<{}>; vuetify: any; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<Vue,
> object, object, object, never>'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'vuetify' does not exist in type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<Vue,
> object, object, object, never>'.   Overload 2 of 3, '(options?:
> ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<Vue, object, object, object,
> object> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<Vue, object, object, object,
> Record<...>>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ router: VueRouter; store: Store<{}>; vuetify: any; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<Vue,
> object, object, object, object>'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'vuetify' does not exist in type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<Vue,
> object, object, object, object>'.   Overload 3 of 3, '(options?:
> ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData, DefaultMethods,
> DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<...>> |
> undefined): CombinedVueInstance<...>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ router: VueRouter; store: Store<{}>; vuetify: any; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData,
> DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string,
> any>>, Record<...>>'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'vuetify' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData,
> DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string,
> any>>, Record<...>>'.
> 11 |   router,
> 12 |   store,
>
> > 13 |   vuetify,
> > |   ^
> > 14 |   render: h => h(App)
> > 15 | }).$mount('#app')
> > 16 | ERROR in C:/Test/vue-test/src/plugins/vuetify.ts(2,21):
> > 2:21 Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuetify/lib'.
> > 'C:/Test/vue-test/node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js'
> > implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install @types/vuetify` if it
> > exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vuetify/lib';`
> > 1 | import Vue from 'vue';
> > 2 | import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
> > |                     ^
> > 3 |
> > 4 | Vue.use(Vuetify);
> > 5 | Version: typescript 3.8.3 Time: 1997ms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a good answer here:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugins/issues/112#issuecomment-562935079

No need to add `typeRoots` though.

Simply add `vuetify` to `types` under `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json.`

Example:

```
"types": [
  "webpack-env",
  "mocha",
  "chai",
  "vuetify"
],
```

Comment: I was able to solve a similar issue (with Vuelidate) just by installing the `@types` package for the library in question (no modifications to `tsconfig`).